# Writing Java 7 library code to work well with Java 8 lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, backwards-compatibility, java-8

I'm writing library code that needs to run and compile in Java 7, so I can't use the new lambda features in Java 8 directly.

However I'd still like the code to be convenient to use with Java 8. For example:

- It would be helpful if inner classes / vistor style patterns could be used as Lambdas by Java 8 users
- I'd like to provide APIs that are convenient for usage with lambdas

What practices should I apply to ensure the best possible experience for both Java 7 and Java 8 users of my library?

Comment: Being as lamda's are client side only - i.e. the consuming method has no idea it is being handed a lambda - none. Just write your code as you normally would. You _might_ what to try and proivde more single methods interfaces than you otherwise would - i.e. asking for two parameters that are both SMIs rather than a single parameter that does both tasks - but that will also pollute the code for Java 7 users.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions are based on single-method interfaces. Anywhere where an implementation of a single-method interface is used (for example, an anonymous inner class that implements an interface that has one method), a Java 8 user can use a lambda expression instead.

Have a look at how the collection classes have been modified in Java 8; for example the `forEach` method that was added to `Iterable`. Each of those methods take a single-method interface as an argument.

Have a look at:

- [State of the Lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html)
- [State of the Lambda: Libraries Edition](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-libraries-final.html)

To make your library useable to pre-Java 8 users, you might also want to provide methods that support the old style of iterating over collections; don't force those users to use lots of anonymous inner classes.

Comment: "Anywhere where an implementation of a single-method interface is used..." Not *anywhere*. There are some that cannot be turned into lambdas. For example: anonymous classes that use instance variables, anonymous classes with methods that recursively call themselves, anonymous classes that use `this` inside the code, and anonymous classes where the distinctness of the identity of the anonymous class object is important.